# Make maven add classpath entries to eclipse project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Maven can generate eclipse project files by running "mvn eclipse:eclipse"

When I run some class from Eclipse IDE, it sets classpath entries to

```
target/test-classes
target/classes
*many paths to maven artifacts used in project"
```

However, I'd like to write additional classpath entries in .project
How to make maven to do that?

I use maven 3.1.1

Comment: To sourcefolder or to classfolder or to jars?

Comment: to folder with config files, such as logback.xml

Comment: src/main/resources will be included by default (exactly for config files)

Comment: yes, *src/main/resources* as conventional resourse folder in standard directory layout does the trick. It may be overriden in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

add those additional required entries as dependencies in `pom.xml`,  if those are directories then just edit `.classpath` file

then don't use `eclipse:eclipse` and use

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

in `.classpath` and add entry for your directory

Comment: I don't want to just edit .classpath, because these changes will be lost after next *mvn eclipse:eclipse*. Is there any way to add a folder to maven pom.xml which will be treated as classpath entry?

Comment: You will need to install m2eclipse plugin within eclipse (just saying)

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps:

1. Add another folder as sourcefolder to maven
2. add correct includes to the maven-eclipse-plugin

There is a ppost about configuring eclipse with maven for a scala project, but this should cover exactly your needs. You will simply have to edit the source folders and the include pattern:

https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/With_Maven_CLI

** update **

or use the default folder for this resources `src/main/resources`